# How to bind a ComboBox with values from db table and avoid duplicates

Tags: c#, database, wpf, combobox, itemssource

In my WPF project I am trying to bind a Combobox to a database table column and avoid duplicates. I'm using Entity Framework.
So far I have been able to succeed binding the Combobox to the column(as EF do most of the work), but I can not get rid of the duplicates.

The thing is my database called Departments has 2 columns. One named DepartmentID and one named DepartmentName. The DepartmentName is the one I want and the one that has the duplicates(which is not a mistake in the setup).
I also have a table called Employees with a foreign key reference to DepartmentID.

I have tried a few suggestions using LINQ and creating a list, but without any luck. I have tried using Filter with a collectionViewSource. I have tried with a converter. I have tried using Distinct in all sorts of ways, and lately I have tried grouping the DepartmentNames. None of it with success.

Here is what is currently showing the DepartmentNames but with a lot of duplicates.

Resources:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="employeeViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Employee}, CreateList=True}"/>
```

The combobox:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="departmentNameComboBox" DataContext="{StaticResource employeeViewSource}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Department.DepartmentName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
```

All I really want, is for that damn ComboBox to show only different department names. I thought it would be easy, but having spend the whole day yesterday, it seems I isn't. At least not for me. :-) Can anyone help?

Comment: So the table has duplicates? (Same name and different ids?) Is there a particular employee that is going to be using this so you can filter using the employee table? I.E. You are going to pick an employee lookup and then want this to filter the combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you just create a database object that only selects the columns that you actually need and bind your combobox to that. I find that to be the cleanest solution because you can just change the source table/view and the combobox will just adapt.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but got a little stubborn, so kept searching for another solution. So unless some on comes up with a really clean and simple solution, I think that is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a raw query:

```
var departments = context.Departments
                  .SqlQuery("SELECT Min(DepartmentId), DepartmentName FROM #tmp GROUP BY DepartmentName")
                  .ToList<Department>();
```

Or group the results using LINQ:

```
var departments = (from d in context.Department
        group d by d.DepartmentName into g
        select new Department
        {
            DepartmentId = g.Min(x => x.DepartmentId),
            DepartmentId = g.Key
        }.ToList();
```

Comment: @MortenBalleHansen: Did you try this? What is your current issue?